# Updating a specific resource in a .NET assembly without rebuilding the whole project

Tags: c#, localization, resources, resx, satellite-assembly

I'm working on a .NET project and have encountered a scenario where i need to update a specific resource in a satellite assembly for the Japanese('ja-JP') culture without rebuilding the entire project. Here are the details:

1. Current Setup:

- My project uses resource file(Greeting.ja-JP.resx) for localization.
- I have a satellite assembly for the Japanese culture('ja-JP') containing these resources.

2. Issue:

- I need to make a minor update to a single resource within the 'Greeting.ja-JP.resx' file.
- Rebuilding the entire project is not an option due to project constraints.

3. Steps Taken:

- I've tried manually updating the .resx file within VS and compiling it with Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019.
- I then created a .resources file using resgen. The command is:

  ```
  resgen Greeting.ja-JP.resx Greeting.ja-JP.resources
  ```
- A satellite assembly is created using al.exe. The command is:

  ```
  al -target:lib -embed:Greeting.ja-JP.resources -culture:ja-JP -out:Example.resources.dll
  ```

  ('Example' is the name of the project)
- replaced the Example.resources.dll in in the output directory
  The directory:

  ```
   Example
     bin
       debug
         ja-JP
           Example.resources.dll
         Example.exe
         Example.exe.config
     Greeting.ja-JP.resx
     Greeting.resx
     App.config
     Program.cs
  ```
- after replacing the dll, the source code picks the default value for the string and not the updated one.

4. What I'm seeking:

- how to replace the existing satellite assembly for the Japanese culture without rebuilding the entire project.
- Specific steps or commands I should use to accomplish this task.

Please provide a detailed walkthrough or explanation of the process, as I'm relatively new to working with satellite assemblies.

The source code:

```
string cultures = "ja-JP";
CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo(cultures[cultureNdx]);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Example.Greeting",
                                      typeof(Example).Assembly);
string greeting = String.Format("The current culture is {0}.\n{1}",
                              Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name,
                               rm.GetString("HelloString")); // HelloString is the key in resx
MessageBox.Show(greeting);
```

Comment: When the assembly this satellite assembly should be loaded for is signed the satellite assembly needs also to be signed.

Comment: there is no signing involved in this process